# C# - Xamarin - how to debug a "using ..." error?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm using MSVS2015Pro for Xamarin.

I downloaded the project: https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

But I'm getting an error on:

```
using Clans.Fab;
```

It says:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Clans' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) FAB.Sample  D:\Xamarin\FloatingActionButton-Xamarin.Android\FAB.Sample\FloatingActionMenuBehavior.cs    5   Active

as you can see on the following image:

[image]

**[EDIT]**

On the following image you have more details on errors:

[image]

**My question is:**

how can I debug these kind of errors?, I mean, not this one specifically but when there are `using errors` in general?. How can I know what: `Clans.Fab;` specifically is needed and from where do I have to download it?

**[EDIT]**

Then I did:

```
PM> Install-Package FAB.XamarinAndroid
```

and the errors disappeared and now I have 255 warnings.
Any idea on how to fix these warnings?

Below you have an screenshot with them:

[image]

Any idea on how to get rid of these warnings?

Comment: try finding it on nuget

Comment: this worked. I did: **Install-Package FAB.XamarinAndroid**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio projects you download from github should contains all external references pointing to nuget packages and you restore them on first build (unless project is not configured to restore on build).

Local references are either framework references you should have installed on your machine or other projects inside the solution.

Normally a missed class will be paired with a yellow exlamation symbol on references list indicating that a necessary assembly could not be loaded, that could be a first check to do.

Output window from build could also provide insights about any anomaly related to references.

Comment: but I would need to know how to solve this kind of errors. I edited my question adding another image. Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: @nightclub: what do you see if you expand "references" on `FAB.Sample`? Any yellow exclamation symbol?

Comment: I did: "**PM> Install-Package FAB.XamarinAndroid**" and there is no errors now. So right now I can't tell you :(. In the other hand, now I have 255 warnings. I'm gonna update my initial post with an screenshot of these warnings.

Comment: @nightclub: you should not need to do that. I believe warning are related to the fact that now you have duplicated references. I'd download the project again and start over.

Comment: you are right, I redownloaded the project and it is working now. I just did: Rebuild. Thanks!